# How to make db connection in php of on other server A to sever B

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to make db connection my php scripts on server A and connect to the MySQL database on server B?

Comment: Make sure that MySQL remote connection is enabled

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put up some code

Comment: <?php

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
if (!function_exists('mysql_init') && !extension_loaded('mysql')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
   // echo 'Phew we have it!';
}

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//mysql_select_db($dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
}
?>

Comment: Don't paste code in the comments, please. Edit your question and paste it there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

This should work just fine.

```
$conn = new mysqli(223.122.212.2:90, 'root', 'root');
```

where `223.122.212.2` is `ip` to server B, running mysql server and listening on port 90. Make sure that server B is running mysql on port 90 (or any other port you'd like) and firewall, if any, configured in a way that allows remote connection.

```
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: Also make sure that the user connecting has the rights to connect from remote hosts

Comment: can you confirm; mysql is running on server B and on which port it is running. also confirm your mysql username and password ( on server B )

Comment: if on linux, confirm on terminal by typing: `mysql -u root -h 223.122.212.2 -P 90 -p
`

Comment: i am using two cpanel for the access database so how to work

Comment: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do few steps:

- On server B, Make enable remote access to database
- On server A, db connection file make host => IP of server b

Comment: how can i enable ?

Comment: sir I have two server 
i have all information about server A for use the database but i dont know how to use the database on other server(server B)

Comment: You need to follow these steps. https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/